# How to prove these triangle relations?

Tags: geometry, triangles

$O$ is the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$, whereas $G$ is the centroid and $H$ is the orthocenter. $R$ denotes the circumradius. How can I prove the following relations:

1. $OH^2=9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.
2. $OG=\frac13 OH=2 HG$

I honestly don't have any ideas. Any hints would appreciated :)

Comment: Please see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [second](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/emt668.student.folders/BrombacherAarnout/write-up%203.aarnout/Eulerlineproof.html), you can prove your first result by vectors. Take origin at circumcentre. hence, $\vec {OH}=\vec a+\vec b+\vec c$ and $\vec {OG}=\vec{GH}/3$

$|\vec a+\vec b+\vec c|^2=\vec{OH}.\vec{OH}$

Note that $|\vec a|=R$ and same with other two and angles between them is twice of angle subtended at vertex(remember theorem from circles?)

$OH^2=R^2(3+2(\sum\cos 2A))=R^2(1-8\prod \cos A)$. You should be able to simplify now.

If you want a proof for centroid one, google Ceva's theorem.